# Is there a way to remove the border around a separator?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to remove the green so that, when I resize the separator, it just shows the thin separator.

[image: The image]

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the minimum height and preferred height to 0, because in that example it looks like you have it at preferred size.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it